# Can I dynamically change a CSS Grid depending on how many items are in it?

Tags: css, grid, dynamically-generated

The following is my code:

```css
.dashboard {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
}

.dashboard-event {
  /* width: 1237px; */
  height: 368px;
  background: #242424;
  border: 2px solid #c2ad7e;
  border-radius: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard">
  <div class="dashboard-event"></div>
  <div class="dashboard-event"></div>
</div>
```

The amount of items in the HTML is fixed at the moment, but will be dynamic, depending on how many events are ongoing at the moment.
When there is only 1 event running, I want this one event stretch 100% to the end.
When there are more than 1 event, I want to display up to 3 items in one row. In this case would be:
`grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);`

Is it possible to do this dynamically?
Right now, when there is only one, it keeps the length of 1 / 2